# Do While Loop Idiocy

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I didn't do a good job explaining the first time.  What I'm trying to do is take a workbook, pull a budget center from the sheet set as BCD, paste that budget center into a cell on sheet set as IGE, have the macro perform a bunch of tasks (including valuing a bunch of cells), save the file as the budget center number, then take the next budget center number, copy and paste it and perform the same tasks including saving the file as the budget center name and repeat until the last budget center has been reached.  I can get everything to work great for the first budget center, but then the macro stops after the first file has been saved.  I can open up the template again, but the macro thinks it's finished.  I hope that's more clear.  And thanks.

```
Sub RunMacro()

Dim OpenPath As String
Dim OpenName As String
Dim BCD As Worksheet
Dim IGE As Worksheet
Dim LAE As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim lr As Integer
Dim lc As Integer
Dim SavePath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim LastRow As Long


OpenPath = "\\filer01\financedrv\budget\" & Year(Date) + 1 & " Budget\"  'Sets the save path for the file
OpenName = "Budget Center Template 2019.xltm"

Set BCD = Worksheets("Budget Center Data")
Set IGE = Worksheets("input gen'l exp")
Set LAE = Worksheets("input lae")

BCD.Activate

LastRow = BCD.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

Do While LastRow <> 0

For y = 1 To 1
For x = 2 To 200 Step 1
If BCD.Cells(x, y).Value <> "" Then
    BCD.Cells(x, y).copy
    IGE.Range("B4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If

IGE.Activate

For c = 3 To 3                                                                      'Sets the column to the third column (C)
For r = 11 To 1500 Step 1
If Cells(r, c).Value <> Year(Date) + 1 Then
    Cells(r, c).Offset(0, 2).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight).Offset(, -1)).copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.Locked = True
    Cells(r + 1, c).Activate
End If
Next r
Next c

Range("B4:B6").copy
Range("B4:B6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("Q4:Q6").copy
Range("Q4:Q6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

LAE.Activate

For lc = 3 To 3                                                                      'Sets the column to the third column (C)
For lr = 11 To 250 Step 1
If Cells(lr, lc).Value <> Year(Date) + 1 Then
    Cells(lr, lc).Offset(0, 2).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight).Offset(, -1)).copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.Locked = True
    Cells(lr + 1, lc).Activate
End If
Next lr
Next lc

Range("B4:B6").copy
Range("B4:B6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("Q4:Q6").copy
Range("Q4:Q6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

IGE.Protect Password:="Max" & Year(Date) + 1
LAE.Protect Password:="Max" & Year(Date) + 1

Sheets("Expense Data").Delete
Sheets("LAE Data").Delete
Sheets("Reforecast").Delete

SavePath = "\\filer01\financedrv\budget\" & Year(Date) + 1 & " Budget\"  'Sets the save path for the file
FileName = Sheets("input gen'l exp").Range("B4") & ".xlsx"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (SavePath & FileName), FileFormat:=51                             '51 is xlOpenXMLWorkbook - a macro free workbook

Workbooks.Open FileName:=OpenPath & OpenName

Next x
Next y

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain what isn't working with the above.

Comment: FWIW there's no shame in asking on SO, thousands do it every day. Or, every single one of us *is* also an idiot ;-)

Comment: I think I'm confused on what you want to do, are you just wanting to check the first cell in every row up to row number 200?

Comment: Don't you need to give `x` and `y` a value *before* invoking `Do While BCD.Cells(x,y)...`?  Even if not, do you need `For y = 1 to 1 ?` If I'm reading this correctly, `Do While` will *always* use `x=200` since when the `For y = 1...` loop ends, and you hit `Loop`, `x` will be `200` every time.

Comment: You only need 1 loop here - to loop through non-empty cells in Column A, starting in row 2. You can use a `For` loop, such as `For x = 2 to lastRow`, where you've previously determined `lastRow`. You could use a `For Each` loop, such as `For Each rng in MyRange`, where you've figured out `MyRange` previously. Or you could use a `Do...Loop While` loop. Just pick one and go with it.

Comment: `For y = 1 To 1`... so run the code contained in this loop once? (which is how many times it would be run even if it wasn't in this loop). Really think through each iteration that is going to happen here as if you were the computer. After you think through three or four iterations I think you'll see that you only need a single loop.

Comment: ^ what he says. Also consider adding a breakpoint (F9), say on the `Do While` line, then stepping through (F8) line by line while monitoring the values in the *locals* toolwindow (View ~> Locals).

Comment: I think can we stake a step back? @BaggerTom this may be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What are you trying to do, can you kindly clarify? You may be overcomplicating things with that Do loop.  Also, it may help you visualize/understand what's happening, if you step through the code with `F8`.  This will take you line-by-line and you can watch what's happening and see what goes "wrong" where.